# How to replace arbitrary nodes in config file using xpath under Octopus?

Tags: xpath, config, octopus-deploy

Question to people experienced with Octopus.

This is about very basic functionality which seems to be surprisingly missing in Octopus. It is about replacing any arbitrary node in the config file using XPath syntax and **not** Octopus variables (which is BTW advised on https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/configuration-files and is a really poor solution as it requires a new release for each time you need to replace a new element or attribute in the config file).

I could write a command line application that could do this in an hour or so but would it be then possible to integrate it with Octopus. E.g. in a way the application is run for each variable present in on the Variable list?

Second question, I would need to store XPath expression along the value somewhere, possibly variable name, however it would have to be encoded somehow. 
Maybe storing variables in some arbitrary but editable from the Octopus WebUI text file? Does it have any such a feature anyway?

If you have any solution for that, please could you share it?

Comment: 1) what's wrong with the Octopus variable replacement method that's not fit for your usage? 2) it is absolutely correct to have a new release for changing the config file. What are the downsides to this in your opinion? P.S. please tag me so I get a notification of your resposne :)

Comment: @gvee: Well, there are a couple of fundamental things: first, limiting the number of variables to enter in the Octopus variable page. This page is so horrible that it does not even deserve an alpha version, but its at version 3.17: No import/export, no group handling, no default scopes, keyboard handling is broken, mouse focus disappearing, no history of changes, no ordering... So with XPath (or anything similar) you could only change what needs to be changed without modifying the project and releasing it. I don't think the page is going to improve soon inspite of many people complaints.

Comment: The variable editor has been improved in v4

Comment: Each time you create a release the state of the variables is captured, you can see these values in the JSON data in the VariableSets table.

Comment: @benPearce: In version 4 you can't even resize the column width (sic!) so it is not possible to see the full name of the variable unless you resize your browser size to multiple screens. Worse, ellipsis is also missing so it is not easy to find out if the name is shortened or not. No multiple variable editing, no import, no custom ordering, no default scopes, no logical grouping, No history for auditing purposes. And so on so on. The new UI is more than horrible. If you are referring to it as an improvement then, frankly speaking, I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a `App.config` file (what I'm about to describe would work just as well for a `Web.config` file). Create a `App.Release.config` file alongside it in the solution. Ensure that this file is included in your Package, with its name changed to correspond with what the App.config file has become. e.g. if App.config has become `MyApp.exe.config`, then it needs to be `MyApp.exe.Release.config`.

Inside that file, you use the [XML document transform syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.100).aspx) (which is based around XML and XPath, and is very easy to pick up), to specify how you want the config file changed. Use Octopus variables as placeholders for the values that you need.

In your Octopus Project's Process you probably have a step like "Deploy Package". At the top of this, next to the Save button is a "CONFIGURE FEATURES" link button. (Not all steps have this... you need to be using one which does.) Untick "Configuration Variables" (read the description: I find this feature is unlikely to ever be of help to me), ensure "Configuration Transforms" is ticked, and tick "Substitute Variables in Files", press OK.

Set up "Substitute Variables in Files" to replace variables in the `MyApp.exe.Release.config` file. If you haven't used the `*.Release.config` name that I've suggested, then you need to configure "Configuration Transforms" to apply your transform file. Don't worry about the order - the substitute will happen before the transform.

Regarding the point *"it requires a new release for each time you need to replace a new element or attribute in the config file"*: if you are able to write the XDT to be future-proof for all the changes you make in future, great. But if not, that XDT config file will be right alongside the config file as a reminder that if you change the config file (which, by the way would mean that you need to create a new Release), then you probably want to change the XDT file as well.

I like to also have Unit Tests against the config file and XDT, to verify that each appSetting, connectionString, and endpoint in the config file is being configured by the XDT. So if I add a new one, and forget to add the XDT, the Unit Test will remind me by failing. Each test has a list of exclusions, where I can add ones that I am intentionally not configuring.

Hope this helps.